# How to create a treeview in c# when Deserialize Json to object?

Tags: c#, json, wpf, restsharp

I'm new into c# and wpf. i have successful deserialize the json data into object by using restsharp.

Currently my json data returns when call a GET method has something looks like this:

```
{  
   "elements":[  
      {  
         "id":1,
         "subject":"New website",
         "_links":{  
            "children":[  
               {  
                  "href":"/api/v3/work_packages/6",
                  "title":"New landing page"
               },
               {  
                  "href":"/api/v3/work_packages/4",
                  "title":"Newsletter registration form"
               },
               {  
                  "href":"/api/v3/work_packages/5",
                  "title":"Implement product tour"
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      {  
         "id":6,
         "subject":"New landing page",
         "_links":{  
            "ancestors":[  
               {  
                  "href":"/api/v3/work_packages/3",
                  "title":"New website"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}

   and more
```

So my question is that how to put it into a treeview template?

```
public class Outer
    {
        public List<RootObjectForAncestor> elements { get; set; }
        public List<RootObjectForChild> elements { get; set; }
    }
public class RootObjectForAncestor
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string subject { get; set; }
        public LinksChild _links { get; set; }
    }
public class LinksChild
    {
        public List<Child> children { get; set; }
    }
public class Child
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
    }
####and this below for the child class #####
public class RootObjectForChild
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string subject { get; set; } 
        public LinksAncestor _links { get; set; }
    }

public class Ancestor
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
    }
public class LinksAncestor
    {
        public List<Ancestor> ancestors { get; set; }
    }
```

My function for getting normal get method looks like this

```
        var client = new RestClient("my endpoint");
        client.Authenticator = newHttpBasicAuthenticator("apikey","myapikey");

        var request = new RestSharp.RestRequest("api/v3/projects/1/work_packages", Method.GET);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Outer>(response.Content);
```

So the question is how do i put these binding into the treeview?

Comment: Always do some research before asking. See here https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/630300/JSON-Viewer

Comment: The json is your model - the base data. If binding directly to that does not suit ( and it often doesn't ) then it  is usual to translate that into viewmodels which suit the view and bind them. Then back again if you're editing.